# Do you need to turn off UPnP on Router and/or Modem?

Tags: router, modem, upnp

When cascading router and modem, do you need to disable UPnP feature on router? I mean, is it not the modem's job to take care of that?

Comment: It entirely depends if you require UPnP to work.  If you have say a Xbox connected to a router which is connected to router that is connected to your modem.  If your modem is the only device that supports UPnP it means you won't be forwarding ports to your Xbox dynamically.

Comment: I do not understand. So that means router has nothing to do with port forwarding as long as I disable that feature right?

Comment: Your question specifically asks about UPnP.  If you need to forward multiple ports due to a device that uses multiple port, and that service can exist say on multiple Windows 10 machines on the same network, UPnP is a good solution to that problem.

Comment: What if I were connecting to the internet? So according to you, it should make sense to enable UPnP on Modem because Router cannot handle that "service"

Comment: Lot's of routers support UPnP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't *need* to, but doing so can be advantageous from a security point of view.